# Error 2013: lost connection to mariadb when adding full text index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mariadb, full-text-indexing

I am using **Maria DB 10.1.8** latest stable version available and i have dumped around 15 Million records into table `more_bar_codes` table. When i tried to alter table to add `fulltext` index onto one of its column, am getting error

> 2013: lost connection to mysql server during query.

The syntax used is:

```
Alter table more_bar_codes add fulltext index  dl_full_text_bar_code (bar_code);
```

Any idea how to fix this one?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`.  What tool are you using for issuing the command?  The mysql commandline tool?

Comment: @Rick James, Yes am using command line to execute the queries. <br/> 
connect_timeout             = 20
deadlock_timeout_long       = 50000000
deadlock_timeout_short      = 10000
delayed_insert_timeout      = 300
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    = 50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  = OFF
interactive_timeout         = 28800
lock_wait_timeout           = 31536000
net_read_timeout            = 30
net_write_timeout           = 60
slave_net_timeout           = 3600
thread_pool_idle_timeout    = 60
wait_timeout                = 28800

Comment: Is `autocommit` OFF?  It probably should be ON.

Comment: Time it  next time.  See which `timeout` it matches.

Answer (score 0):

No timeout worked for me. One workaround is to create temp table like old table and add full text index and then copy data to it. That has resolved my issue.